# Elasticsearch external access on google cloud platform?

Tags: elasticsearch, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I got a weird issue with opening 9200 port on gce. After:

1. Run VM in compute engine (Ubuntu 16.04) - yes, I know CentOS...not yet :-)
2. Install elasticsearch
3. `gcloud compute --project realty4-1384 firewall-rules create allow-elasticsearch --allow TCP:9200 --target-tags elasticsearch`

but sad Dinosaur saying that connection refused.....
curl localhost:9200 - works
nginx, varnish works in the same condition. 
 I suspect something with rights maybe somebody can give me a hint. 
THANK YOU

Comment: Two questions about your GCE instance:

- is it using the 'default' network?
- does it have the elasticsearch tag?

Comment: yes, Vilas. It's exactly what I have, but connection refused :(. SOrry I missed your question - thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

It was a huge torture for me, I tried to build elasticsearch to docker container and used kubernetes like orchetrator, all works perfectly
until I start getting traffic. My aggregations tear everything apart.

So I have to find a way, spent a day with nginx nothing. Finally,
haproxy did worked for me:

1. sudo apt-get install haproxy
2. sudo vim sudo vim /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
3. add after default section

   `listen elastic
   bind 0.0.0.0:9500
   mode http
   option forwardfor
   server elastic 127.0.0.1:9200 check`

Make sure to open 9500 with tcp and IT DOES WORK!

Comment: *grumble* But why doesn't that work for default with elasticsearch?  There must be a shortcut to enable what you did, but without using haproxy?

Comment: When having connection issues in GCE there are usually three places to look at:
1- There is a service in the VM configured to [listen](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/articles/win_net_srv/netstat.html) on all the interfaces and that particular port. 
2- There is a defined rule allowing connections on [Google Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking). 
3- There is no firewall inside the VM (i.e iptables) blocking the connections.

Comment: logically, you should go to /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml and set host to your ip... but it does not work :-). I am not saying it's the best solution, but I did not have an issue with haproxy. Do not forget to enable it systemctl.

Comment: P.S. And set everything with ansible, do it once and forget about headaches 
Good luck guys!

Comment: You just saved my life!